# Relevant statistical test for data of a ranking experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ranking, friedman-test

I'm currently thinking of a relevant statistical test to use to assess the results
of a small study.

Imagine i have 6 different brand of a food product and i want to know whether the participants to my study are able to tell them appart, and which one they prefer.

Here is what i did so far, i say that my H0 is that all products are the same, the participants cannot tell them appart.
I design a experiment where each participant gets a sample of the 6 products and has to rank them from the best to the worst. Rank 0 is the product they preferred the most, Rank 5 is the product they least preferred.

I end up with data of this form (e.g. with 5 participants) (products are labelled A,B,C,D,E,F)

```
name, rank 0, ..., rank 5
John,C,E,A,D,F,B
Patrick,B,E,D,A,C,F
Sarah,E,A,B,C,D,F
Mary,A,C,D,E,F,B
Jane,C,B,A,F,D,E
```

My question is: Does my protocol seem ok ? if yes, what statistical test are relevant in this situation to assess if there is significant differences of preference between the products ?

I tried the following:
Mannwhitney test, conover, friedman test between pairs, all give very different results, but i can't really wrap my head around what test would be relevant in my case ? (and should it be corrected ?)

Also how much participants should i have and how can I compute the confidence in my results based on the number of participants ?

Comment: Friedman test is most natural in your case. But you should re-format your data. Let the 6 variables (columns) be the 6 brands, while the data values be the ranks. Thus, you will have the set of values 0 through 5, in each row. The test will check your H0 as you has put it. You then can go on to do post-Friedman post hoc pairwise or step-down tests to see which brands significantly win or lose to which.

Comment: I didnt mention it in the question, but yes, my results are melted as you describe. I'm using https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/ as a library , do you have any idea on which friedman i should use ? conover friedman, miller friedman, nememyi friedman ?
Also, any corrections i should make ? Considering my number of participants might be small.
Thx for your answer

Comment: These are post-hoc options. Read about them. The last one is most frequently used, but you should select yourself.